# Wide characters cause visual artifacts on weechat

Tags: terminal, utf-8, weechat

I have some wide characters (◀▬▬ / ▬▬▶) set up as the join/part indicators in weechat. However, they tend to bleed over when I switch windows. How do I prevent this from happening?

[image: normal look]

Above is how it should look, and how it looks after I redraw the window (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

[image: issue]

Above image clearly displays the bleed-over effect, which happens after switching windows, and when the channel gets another message (so the window contents get moved up one or more lines). The artifacts do not show up when another character is redrawin in the place of the old character.

These are the relevant weechat settings: (`weechat.look.`)

[image: weechat.conf]

Here you can see the settings in `weechat.conf`.

This all happens independently from tmux and mosh/ssh. I am using the GNOME3 gnome-terminal, using the Ubuntu Mono font at size 13.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is an issue unrelated to weechat, but with either your terminal emulator, font, or possibly the OSs handling. Are you using a "__.5" font size? I know that this can be handled quite oddly in my experience.

Comment: I am using the GNOME3 gnome-terminal, using the Ubuntu Mono font at size 13.